# JavaScript to add a comma after a name

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help with a JavaScript that will add a comma after information mapped from another program?  I am creating a form letter that will draft information from a program and I would like to put a comma after their name.  Such as `Jane Smith` in the program will turn into `Jane Smith,` on the form.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: Show us the whole string you get from this other program. Also, if you have tried something already, post your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = name + ","
```

will add a comma to a string called name.  You'll have to give more info if you want to know how to pull that name from another program.